# Get IP from e-mails in IMAP mailbox

Tags: php, email, geolocation, ip-address

Hello
 I am looking to write an independent script to log into an e-mail account [IMAP], get the headers for each e-mail, locate & store the (sender's or server's) IP address from each one. I recognize that this has to be a bit comprehensive to cover the top 3 webmail providers (Yahoo, Google & Hotmail) as well as the other common header formats.

Ideally, I would like to get the senders' IP addresses, but would settle for the servers' IP addresses.

I need to do this in PHP in a regular LAMP setup.

Any ideas would help. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "IP address from each one"? Doing that is a task in itself (and many mail services don't include the dynamic IP of the originating machine any more)

Comment: I would like to locate & store the IP address from the header of each e-mail received in the IMAP mailbox.

Comment: You are repeating yourself, but it is still not clear what you are wanting to do here. IP addresses are allocated to computers/servers on a network. Are you wanting to "locate & store" the addresses for the IP Address of a server the message comes from, a server the message comes through (there can be more than one) or the computer the sender used to create the email?

Comment: @Lucanos I get it now, I would like to get the senders' IP addresses, but would settle for servers' IP addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details of the servers the system transits through are shown in the top of the email header in reverse-chronological order - the most recent are at the top, the first servers are at the bottom.

A quick, off-the-cuff solution would be to use a RegExp to try and find the bottom "Received:..." line containing an IP address.

A very quick test suggests that:

```
$regExp = '/Received:.*((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)/';
```

will match the lines, and return IP addresses.

Then you'd just use something like `preg_match_all()` to return an array of matched lines, and use the last one of the lot.

Comment: In $matches[1], ip's are trucated from 123.123.123.123 to 3.123.123.123, but you could just use $matches[0] and do another regex on the last element in $matches[0] I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

That IP is IP of server who mailed it, not the sender IP. Do you want servers IP or senders IP?

Comment: Ah now I get it. I would like to get the senders' IP addresses, but would settle for servers' IP addresses.

Comment: @Abhic: In many cases the senders' IP addresses will be useless to you as a lot of PCs are on private networks. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Answer (score 0):

After you connected, got the messages list and now is foreaching a message:

```
$header=imap_fetchheader($imap,$msgn);
$regex='/client\-ip\=(.+?)\;/s';
preg_match_all($regex,$header,$matches);
$clientip=echo($matches[1]);
```

It works like a breeze for me.

Comment: Looks good, but header does not contain a "client-ip" tag, for me anyways.

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is old but the above selected answer does get an IP but it does not necessarily get the correct sending server IP address. Below is the regex I used to get the actual sending servers IP:

```
/^Received:\sfrom(.*)[\[\(]\s*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})[\]\)]/im
```